# Magento update product from SOAP

Tags: web-services, api, magento, soap, product

Magento 1.9.1.0, SOAP, WS-I compliant. i'm trying to update product qty, magento returns "success", qty stays as it was before (didn't changed). How to change product qty from SOAP ?

request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdateRequestParam xmlns="urn:Magento">
            <sessionId xmlns="">32efdfffb0f27f43f3ee0073a9351de3</sessionId>
            <productIds xmlns="">
                <complexObjectArray>9198</complexObjectArray>
            </productIds>
            <productData xmlns="">
                <complexObjectArray>
                    <qty>17</qty>
                    <is_in_stock>1</is_in_stock>
                </complexObjectArray>
            </productData>
        </catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdateRequestParam>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdateResponseParam>
            <result>true</result>
        </ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdateResponseParam>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: The code above works for another magento store. But doesn't works current store

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and it worked

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdateRequestParam>
         <sessionId>ddaf6e2b9bf7055ae59b7cbeeca9c894</sessionId>
         <productIds>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <complexObjectArray>764</complexObjectArray>
         </productIds>
         <productData>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <complexObjectArray>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <qty>9</qty>

               <use_config_notify_stock_qty>1</use_config_notify_stock_qty>
            </complexObjectArray>
         </productData>
      </urn:catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdateRequestParam>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here are the results

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdateResponseParam>
         <result>true</result>
      </ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdateResponseParam>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is a screen shot of the updated qty
[image]

Comment: Thank you, i tried your code, but it doesn works. I receve 'success', but qty didn't changed.

Comment: I would see if you have a module that may be hijacking the request to return a different result. I am testing on a pretty clean version of enterprise 1.14 and community 1.9 with success. Also if you can verify that the core files are unmodified. The sample code I provided should work.